# How to pass Angular 2 form input to typescript component?

Tags: json, forms, angular, typescript, angular2-forms

I am new to angular 2.I am looking for a way to pass the form input values to the ts component ,to send to spring controller as a JSON string.The basic form I have created is as follows

person.component.html

```
    <div class="panel-body">
    <div class="row">   
    <div class="col-sm-1"><label class="control-label" for="Name">Full Name:
   </label></div>
    <div class="col-sm-3">
    <input type="text" class="form-control2" placeholder="Full Name" 
    [(ngModel)]="user.name"></div></div>  
    <br>
    <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-1"><label class="control-label" for="Email">Email:</label></div>
        <div class="col-sm-3">
            <input type="text" class="form-control2"  [(ngModel)]="user.email">
        </div>
   </div>
   <br>
    <div class="col-sm-9">              
                <button class="btn1" (click)="savePage()"><b>Save</b></button>
            <button class="btn1" (click)="resetPage()"><b>Cancel</b></button>
                </div>  </div>
```

person.ts

```
export class Person {
    constructor(
        public name: string,
        public email: string,
            ) {  }
}
```

What is to be done further?

Comment: Add public properties name & email in Person class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing it already! 
`[(ngModel)]="user.name"` - this is so called two way binding.
Now, in your typescript file, object `user` is filled with your inputs' values
Now you would need some kind of service, i.e. `user.service.ts` which needs to be specified in your Component's providers.

//component

```
@Component({
  [...]
  providers: [UserService]
})


export class SomeComponent {

  user: User = new User();

  public SomeComponent(private _userService: UserService) {}

  public addUser(): void {
    this._userService.addUser(this.user).subscribe(res => {
      console.log(res); //whatever
    });
  }
}
```

//service

```
public addUser(user: User) {
    return this.http.post(this.host + this.apiPrefix + '/users/', JSON.stringify(user),
      {headers: <your headers>})
    .map((res: any) => {
      return res;
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using `[(ngModel)]` your `Person.ts` look like this

```
export class Person {
    name: string;
    email: string; 
}
```

then import it in `person.component.ts`

```
import { Person  } from 'person.ts';
```

and inside your class `PersonComponent` declare `user:Person;`
then call `this.user = new Person();` like this in `constructor`

now `[(ngModel)]` will map the data for you.

Answer (score 0):

In TypeScript you can do things like:

```
export class Person {
  name: string;
  email: string;
}

const email = 'some mail';
const name = 'some name';
const person: Person = { name: name , email:email }
```

In your case it would be:

```
const person: Person = {name: user.name, email: user.email}
```

or just

```
const person: Person = user;
```

In the end you just need to make sure, that the properties match.
If you have, for example, a methode like this:

```
 someMethod(input: Person): void {}
```

You can pass your user object as an parameter:

```
 someMethod(user); <--- this will work;
```